# How to invoke Java code on press of the submit button

Tags: jsf, form-submit

I have a working JSF application that allows a user to enter their name, press the Submit button, and they are presented with a page that welcomes them.

The structure is very simple, there is a Person bean that has a setter and getter for a name, and the textfield sets the name, and the welcome page gets the name from the bean to present it on the welcome page.

My question is can I invoke java methods from XHTML when the user presses the Submit button, because I need to open a connection to the database. The code for the first page of the application looks like this in the xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
 <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
 <h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
  <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
 </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

So it looks like when they hit Welcome Me, the welcome.xhtml file is called up and the bean is passed to it. But I also need to execute some code to open the database when the Welcome Me button is pressed, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, the `action` attribute of the command button should be bound to the action method of the bean.

```
<h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="#{helloBean.submit}" />
```

In the method you've all the freedom to write down Java code which should be executed when the button is pressed.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "welcome";
}
```

The returned string will be used as navigation outcome. If you return `null` or `void`, it will return to the same view.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean, but if I do that, how does the application know what .xhtml page to render when Welcome Me is pressed?

Comment: The return value of the method is used as navigation case outcome. In my particular code example, it will just go to exactly the same page as in your initial code. I warmly recommend to checkout our JSF wiki page, you'll find therein another Hello World example and several links to decent JSF tutorials. The question which you're asking is basically already covered in chapter 1 of a decent JSF tutorial (and thus extremely basic).

Comment: Ok, I'll check out the wiki, thaks.

Comment: The `action="welcome"` will just navigate to the given page. It's exactly like as `public String submit() { return "welcome"; }` wherein further *nothing else* is been performed. The `action="#{bean.method}"` allows you to perform some Java code before `"welcome"` is returned.

Comment: Ok, I tried to subsitute the code in the action section for the {helloBean.submit}, and when I hit submit I got 'Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/hello.xhtml' for action '#{helloBean.submit}' with outcome 'welcome'. So I guess I need to learn how to use the navigation-rule section of the faces-config.xml file?

Comment: If it failed like that, then your initial code snippet would also have faild exactly like that.

Comment: The cause is by the way a missing `welcome.xhtml` file in the same base folder. Since JSF2 you don't need navigation rule boilerplate anymore for simple navigation cases.